# Flux.onErrorContinue() null object

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I have an issue with onErrorContinue() that the object passed to the Biconsumer is null.

I'm using Spring boot 2.1.13.RELEASE and reactive mongo with reactor-core version 3.2.15.RELEASE.

The problem happens when a call to the database to retrieve a record with the id returns no record and using the operator switchIfEmtpy() i throw an exception using Mono.error() and downstream i try to handle this exception using onErrorContinue().

The code below explains the issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux.range(1, 10)
            .flatMap(integer -> mapInteger(integer))
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> System.out.println("error with " + o)) // o is null
            .subscribe();
}

public static Mono<Integer> mapInteger(Integer num) { // This is here to simulate the db call
    return Mono.just(num)
            .flatMap(t -> {
                if (t == 5)
                    return Mono.empty();
                else
                    return Mono.just(num * 2);
            })
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Error happened while mapping integer!")));
}
```

This will print the below values:

```
2
4
6
8
error with null
12
14
16
18
20
```

PS. I don't have the issue when another error happens in the stream.

Update:
The mapInteger() was to simulate the below call to reactivemongo repository:

```
public Mono<MetaData> getFromDbByKey(String key) {
        return repository
            .findByKeyAndDeletedIsFalse(key)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new RuntimeException()));
    }
```

and the call to getFromDbByKey() returns this MetaData which i need to map it to the flux in the main flow.

with onErrorContinue, we catch the Throwable and based on its type we do different handling to each type of error.

Comment: as a workaround, you could change code: `.flatMap(t -> { if (t == 5) throw new RuntimeException("Error happened while mapping integer value " + t);`
and you could log this exception message inside `onErrorContinue `

Comment: `onErrorContinue` is an advanced operator, are you 100% sure you need it and cannot use one of the other `onError` handlers ? (including inside the `flatMap`, appended to `mapInteger`)

Comment: the `null` comes from the fact that, at the point where there is an error, the only signal that happened is `onComplete`. so there is no data signal to pass to the handler, hence the `null`

Comment: @VasylSarzhynskyi Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I can't do this...I also updated the post to clarify why i can't do this as in my real code it's a call to the database

Comment: @SimonBaslé Thanks for the explanation.
Yes, we need to use it as we handle errors differently...in some cases we save to a database and later a scheduler would decide what to do and in some other cases a log is enough.
Another solution which was suggested by a college is to create a custom RuntimeException and include the object that caused the problem inside it.

Comment: @SimonBaslé Please don't remove onErrorContinue() in later releases :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution/workaround that was suggested to me by a colleague:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Flux.range(1, 10)
        .flatMap(integer -> mapInteger(integer)
                           .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(
                                new CustomException("Error happened while mapping integer!", 
                            integer))))
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> {
            if (CustomException.class.isInstance(throwable))
                System.out.println("Object to blame " + ((CustomException)throwable).getBlamedObject());
            System.out.println("error with " + o);
        })
    .subscribe();
  }

  public static Mono<Integer> mapInteger(Integer num) {
      return Mono.just(num)
          .flatMap(t -> {
              if (t == 5)
                  return Mono.empty();
              else
                  return Mono.just(num * 2);
          });
  }

  public static class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
      private Integer blamedObject;

      public CustomException(String message, Integer blamedObject) {
          super(message);
          this.blamedObject = blamedObject;
      }

      public Integer getBlamedObject() {
          return blamedObject;
      }
  }
```

This will return:

```
2
4
6
8
Object to blame 5
error with null
12
14
16
18
20
```

The solution/workaround is to create a custom exception that accepts the object with the error and move the *switchIfEmpty()* to the main flow so that i can get the object that caused the problem and later in the *onErrorContinue()* i can check the exception type and get the object that caused the problem.

This works for me as the *mapInteger()* in the example is just a simulation to a reactive mongo repository which will return empty mono if there is no result found as updated in the original post.

Comment: There are many ways to do the same thing. I gave you an approach , which doesnt require a new class of custom exception.

Comment: You're correct, in simple cases i don't need a new class.
In my case it involves a kafka message which i need to pass to the onErrorContinue() in order to retrieve the needed data and save it in a database for a suitable retry algorithm that will be decided later.

Answer (score 1):

You cant expect to receive the "item" t when you are returning **Mono.empty()** if t==5 ?

This code will print what you need.

```
    Flux.range(1, 10)
        .flatMap(integer -> mapInteger(integer))
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> {
          System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
        })
        .subscribe();
  }
  public static Mono<Integer> mapInteger(Integer num) { // This is here to simulate the db call
    return Mono.just(num)
        .flatMap(t -> {
          if (t == 5)
            return Mono.empty();
          else
            return Mono.just(num * 2);
        })
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("error with " + num)));
  }
```

prints:

```
2
4
6
8
error with 5
12
14
16
18
20
```

And in your actual mongoDB call, you can have something like:

```
public Mono<MetaData> getFromDbByKey(String key) {
        return repository
            .findByKeyAndDeletedIsFalse(key)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new RuntimeException("Couldnt find metadata which is not deleted for the key: " + key)));
    }
```

Comment: This i can't do in my real code, please check the update to the post.

Comment: @AhmedAli Ok. Understood. Please check the answer. I updated

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think this is pretty much similar to what a colleague suggested to me, please check the answer i added as well.